# Passing two queues to Tensorflow training

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to create a train operation based on CIFAR10 example from Tensorflow that uses `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` and my labels comes from the name of the files as mentioned in ([Accessing filename from file queue in Tensor Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051205/accessing-filename-from-file-queue-in-tensor-flow)). How can I use this code with that?

When I try to run the following code, where `path` is a directory with many files:

```
filenames = [path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)][1:]
file_fifo = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames,
                                           shuffle=False,
                                           capacity=len(filenames))
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(file_fifo)
image = tf.image.decode_png(value, channels=3, dtype=tf.uint8)
image.set_shape([config.image_height, config.image_width, config.image_depth])
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
image = tf.divide(image, 255.0)
labels = [int(os.path.basename(f).split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]) for f in filenames]
label_fifo = tf.FIFOQueue(len(filenames), tf.int32, shapes=[[]])
label_enqueue = label_fifo.enqueue_many([tf.constant(labels)])
label = label_fifo.dequeue()
bq = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=16 * batch_size,
                           min_after_dequeue=8 * batch,
                           dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.int32])
batch_enqueue_op = bq.enqueue([image, label_enqueue])
runner = tf.train.queue_runner.QueueRunner(bq, [batch_enqueue_op] * num_threads)
tf.train.add_queue_runner(runner)

# Read 'batch' labels + images from the example queue.
images, labels = batch_queue.dequeue_many(FLAGS.batch_size)
labels = tf.reshape(labels, [FLAGS.batch_size, 1])
```

I get obvious erros, because I know my code doesn't make much sense. I have two FIFO queues `file_fifo` and `label_fifo`, but I don't know how to make my `label_fifo` input of my tf.RandomShuffleQueue.

Can someone help? Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to:

```
filenames = [os.path.join(FLAGS.data_path, f) for f in os.listdir(FLAGS.data_path)][1:]
np.random.shuffle(filenames)
file_fifo = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, shuffle=False, capacity=len(filenames))
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(file_fifo)
image = tf.image.decode_png(value, channels=3, dtype=tf.uint8)
image.set_shape([config.image_height, config.image_width, config.image_depth])
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
image = tf.divide(image, 255.0)

labels = [int(os.path.basename(f).split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]) for f in filenames]
label_fifo = tf.FIFOQueue(len(filenames), tf.int32, shapes=[[]])
label_enqueue = label_fifo.enqueue_many([tf.constant(labels)])
label = label_fifo.dequeue()

if is_train:
    images, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label],
                                                 batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
                                                 num_threads=FLAGS.num_threads,
                                                 capacity=16 * FLAGS.batch_size,
                                                 min_after_dequeue=8 * FLAGS.batch_size)
labels = tf.reshape(label_batch, [FLAGS.batch_size, 1])
```

For training I have:

```
class _LoggerHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    """Logs loss and runtime."""

    def begin(self):
        self._step = -1

    def before_run(self, run_context):
        self._step += 1
        self._start_time = time.time()
        if self._step % int(config.train_examples / FLAGS.batch_size) == 0 or self._step == 0:
            run_context.session.run(label_enqueue_op)
        return tf.train.SessionRunArgs({'loss': loss, 'net': net})
```

and I run training as:

```
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
        checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.train_path,
        hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=FLAGS.max_steps), tf.train.NanTensorHook(loss), _LoggerHook()],
        config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement)) as mon_sess:
        while not mon_sess.should_stop():
            mon_sess.run(train_op)
```

The training starts, but it runs only for the very first step and hangs - maybe because it's waiting for some queue command